# useTranslation hook in i18 takes some time to render the original text

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

i have been using useTranslation hook from [react-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next)

the translation seems to be working fine , but i do have 1 issue Here is the code below

i18 setup

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'pt',
    fallbackLng: 'pt',
    debug: false,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  })

export default i18n
```

and then in my home page i use it like

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

function Home({ history }: PropsType) {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
  <span>{t('home.title')}</span>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: Object) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
    user: state.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = null

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home)
```

The problem is on loading of page the first thing i see is "home.title" shown in page then after 1 second the original content is reflected here, so is there any way i could manage i18 to show only the original content once it parses not the hardcoded string like "home.title"

Comment: Isn't setting `useSuspense: false` specifically saying "don't wait for the files to load before rendering"? (I haven't used that option so I may be misunderstanding it)

Comment: @DBS but setting it to true gives error Uncaught (in promise) Error: App suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.